# Azure Event Hub: Receive events as a batch that were sent to hub as individual messages?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have the following pattern,

Http Trigger Function App -> Event Hub -> Event Hub Listener Function App

Unfortunately, the sender to the HTTP Trigger app sends many individual requests, meaning that the execution of the send to event hub is also a small amount of data per message.

This causes the listener to trigger on every small message, creating many, many files at the end of a data load.

My listener is already configured to receive batch events, and I have seen in the past, that when the listener function was disabled for a while, and then re-enabled, the data would be received in a big batch.

How can I ensure that multiple events are processed in a batch once it gets to the listener, even though their send to the event hub are as individual requests/messages?

Is there some delay setting for the listener, perhaps?

Comment: Reference https://github.com/ciaranodonnell/AzureDemos/tree/master/AzureEventHubs/CompetingConsumersOnEventHub

Comment: It would be helpful to see the signature and configuration for your Function app with the Event Hubs trigger.   It would also be helpful to understand if you're expecting the partitions to have a backlog of events or you're trying to process in real-time as the Http Trigger app sends them.

Comment: @JesseSquire the aim is for the listener to accept incoming messages as fast as possible, but also if there are many messages being sent to event hub within a small timeframe, to then receive as a batch in the listener, not individual messages

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough context available to understand how the `maxEventBatchSize` is configured in your `host.json`, but I'll assume that is set to something larger than 1.  In that case, it sounds like the partitions do not have a backlog of events and are being read as they arrive.  Since there are not enough events to keep the prefetch queue full, events are being dispatched as they stream in.

I'd recommend taking advantage of the `minEventBatchSize` that was added in [v5.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs) of the Event Hubs trigger.  This works with `maxWaitTime` to ask the trigger to wait for a bit and build up a batch rather its default behavior of preferring to maximize throughput.

A minimal example would look something like:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "eventHubs": {
            "maxEventBatchSize" : 100,
            "minEventBatchSize" : 25,
            "maxWaitTime" : "00:05:00",            
            "batchCheckpointFrequency" : 1,
            "prefetchCount" : 300,
        }
    }
}
```

More detail is available in the [host.json settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings) section of the docs.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Now to update Core tools, and make Azurite work again.... somehow.

Comment: I'm using Target Framework netcoreapp3.1, will the host.json be able to use maxWaitTime and minEventBatchSize with that framework? Currently host.json is saying these properties aren't allowed.

Comment: `netcoreapp3.1` reached end-of-life in December, 2022 and is no longer a supported runtime.   That said, so long as you're using the in-proc model and referencing v5.3.0+ of `Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.WebJobs.EventHubs`, this option should be supported.  There's no integration with the Functions host - this feature is supported exclusively by the Event Hubs trigger.

Comment: interesting, I am definitely at v5.3.0 (this is the highest version available), but my host still doesn't see these properties as valid. In fact, when I clean and rebuild, and take a look at the output host file, it ignores these new fields.

Comment: I haven't been able to repro what you're describing.  Would you mind trimming out a small self-contained repro from your app and opening an issue in the Azure SDK repository for us to investigate?   https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues

Comment: Could it be because I'm using VSCode?

Comment: The editor shouldn't have anything to do with it.   So long as you're able to run, control should pass to the trigger, which is responsible for binding its config.

Answer (score -1):

The `MaxBatchSize` parameter of the `EventProcessorOptions` object can be used to receive events in a batch.

To receive events as a batch, you can use the `MaxBatchSize` property of the `EventProcessorOptions` object.

Reference :

Thank for the reference @[ciaranodonnell](https://github.com/ciaranodonnell/AzureDemos/commits?author=ciaranodonnell)

**Sending Message**:

```c
EventHubProducerClient producer = new EventHubProducerClient(namespaceConnectionString, eventHubName);
var batch = await producer.CreateBatchAsync(new CreateBatchOptions { PartitionKey = "this is another string" });
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
batch.TryAdd(new EventData($"This is event {i}"));
}
await producer.SendAsync(batch);
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Receiving Message** :

```c
            EventProcessorOptions options = new EventProcessorOptions
            {
                MaxBatchSize = 100,
                PrefetchCount = 100,
                InvokeProcessorAfterReceiveTimeout = true
            };

            await processorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<MyEventProcessor>(options);
```

- The other possible method is message content contains the specific item. In both ways receive batch. For multiple events are processed in a batch using consumer group to send and receive the messages.

**Output :**

[image]

Reference :

- [event-hub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host.md)

Comment: For best performance, you don't want to keep the `prefetchCount` and `maxBatchSize` set to the same value.   We recommend a 3:1 ratio at minimum.

Comment: Please be aware that your example is using the set of legacy packages which have been deprecated and are not recommended for new development.   The `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` family is the current generation.

Comment: @JesseSquire I have a prefetch count set to 512 and maxbatchsize set to 256. individual messages are received.

Comment: The HTTP Request is initiated by an external caller, this caller sends only a small amount of data per request, so it's not like I can use this suggestion to send batches to event hub.